# How call Permision request many times in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want call `permissionRequest` for getting user photos. When I call `permissionRequest` and user didn't allow permission, then I show alert and when in custom alert user tap in allow button I want show `permissionRequest` again.

For this I try using `photo_manager` or `permission_handler` package. But in both packages when I second time call `permissionRequest()` function not show system `permissionRequest`

```
  void _showGeneralAlert() {
    Alert.show(
      context,
      title: 'Allow photo access',
      button: AlertButton(
          title: 'Allow',
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            _request();
          })
    );
  }

  Future<void> _request() async {
    _permissionStatus = await Permission.photos.request();
    if (_permissionStatus != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      _showGeneralAlert();
    }
  }
```

Comment: try with another phone.

Comment: thanks for answer, but it's not working for all devices

Comment: please post the code then

Answer (score 0):

May be because you permanently denied permission,

For this case you need to ask user to take permission default way(ask to open app settings and take
permission)

```
    if (await Permission.photos.isPermanentlyDenied) {
     // The user opted to never again see the permission request dialog for this
     // app. The only way to change the permission's status now is to let the 
    // user manually enable it in the //systemsettings.
Print("permission permanently denied ");
openAppSettings();
    
}
```

**Update**
If this case not work then check your permission status,

```
var status = await Permission.camera.status;

print("permission status"+status.toString());
```

If they print restricted or permanentlyDenied. Then you need to open setting,otherwise you can ask permission

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I want re-show permition request alert, I don't want open app setting

Comment: if user select deny and don't again checkbox. Means they restrict this permission,and you can't ask for this. So simplify as my code you show a simple popup to describe why your application needs permission,and if they agree then ask,please take this permission.

Comment: It's mean if user select "don't allow" from system request we can't second time show system request alert?

Comment: No no, my means is,if user select "deny" and "dont ask again" both then,system can't ask for permission.its means user permanently denied

Comment: ``Permission.photos.isPermanentlyDenied`` for me returned ``false`` and if I call ``Permission.photos.request()`` it's not show system alert

Comment: I am asking only for permanently denied condition.if you are click only on deny then can ask again for permission.means you can able to show system popup for this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225678/discussion-between-shirsh-shukla-and-ash-khachatryan).